# Doing sudo with SSH.NET SFTP to access files

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I am trying to read/download files from a server over SFTP with [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/). Connection works; I can enumerate the directory of interest; but I'm getting an exception with Message "Permission denied" when I try to read the file contents. (Stack traces below; I didn't see anything else useful--no inner exception.)

*This is probably the issue*: When I `ssh` into the server (with the same key), I have to do `sudo vim` to look at the file contents or it also gives me "Permission denied". Note that it doesn't make me enter a password to use `sudo`. I'm just not sure how this informs a change to my code.

```c#
using Renci.SshNet;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

...

try {

    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo;
    using (var keyStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetSshKey())))
    {
        connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(Domain, Username,
                new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(Username, new PrivateKeyFile(keyStream)));
    }

    // Connect to the server with SFTP
    using var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo);
    client.Connect();
    if (!client.Exists(RemoteFolder))
    {
        throw new Exception("The backup folder was not found!");
    }

    // Save block blobs to local files
    foreach (var file in client.ListDirectory(RemoteFolder))
    {
        if (!file.IsRegularFile) continue; // Skip any directories or links

        var readStream = client.OpenRead(file.FullName);       // Exception thrown HERE!
        var writeStream = File.OpenWrite($"C:\\temp\\{file.Name}");

        readStream.CopyTo(writeStream);

        writeStream.Dispose();
        readStream.Dispose();
    }

} catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestOpen(String path, Flags flags, Boolean nullOnError)
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream..ctor(ISftpSession session, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.OpenRead(String path)
   at Playground.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\Program.cs:line 40
```

I tried `DownloadFile` as well as `BeginDownloadFile` with `EndDownloadFile`, but in those cases `DownloadFile` and `EndDownloadFile` respectively throw a similar "Permission denied" error. Stack Trace:

```
   at Renci.SshNet.Common.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at Renci.SshNet.Common.AsyncResult`1.EndInvoke()
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.EndOpen(SftpOpenAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Renci.SshNet.ServiceFactory.CreateSftpFileReader(String fileName, ISftpSession sftpSession, UInt32 bufferSize)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.InternalDownloadFile(String path, Stream output, SftpDownloadAsyncResult asyncResult, Action`1 downloadCallback)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.DownloadFile(String path, Stream output, Action`1 downloadCallback)
   at Playground.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\Program.cs:line 41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account you use to login with SSH.NET does not have read permissions to the file(s).

There's no functionality in SFTP protocol equivalent to `sudo`.

Though if you are connecting to OpenSSH server, you can instruct it to run the SFTP subsystem/server with elevated privileges using a command like:

```
sudo /bin/sftp-server
```

But you cannot do this directly with SSH.NET. Though, with some modifications of its code, it's probably doable. SSH.NET is open source after all.

For more background, see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

Before you even start hacking this, make sure it's feasible by trying it in WinSCP GUI first.

---

Another option would be to use `sudo` in shell (`SshClient.RunCommand`) to make a copy of the file that is accessible by your SFTP account. But that depends on what are your `sudo` privileges.

---

Or you can try [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) instead, with a code like this:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "...",
};

sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("SftpServer", "sudo /bin/sftp-server");

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Your code
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

The best option is to login directly with the account that has read privileges to the file(s).

For a general discussion on this topic, see:
[Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663)

Comment: I was able to use `SshClient.RunCommand` to create a tarball that could be copied over SFTP--made things easy. I did also look at WinSCP and it will likely come in handy in the future. Thanks!